# Is there a way to select a name from another table if it meets a condition in a CASE

Tags: sql-server, case

I am trying to provide a list of all the skills that have ONLY 1 employee attributed to it and if they only have 1 employee i want to see there first name.

I have tried using a CASE to say that if the count of the skills in <=1 then show the employee name(located in another table called employeee)

```
SELECT es.skillId, COUNT(es.employeeId) 'Number of Skill Holders',
CASE WHEN COUNT(es.employeeId) <= 1 THEN (select e.firstName from Employee e )
ELSE 'No Skill shortage'
END AS 'Skill status'
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeSkill] es
JOIN Employee e ON e.id = es.employeeId
group by es.skillId
```

However I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Answer (score 2):

correlate your `subquery` to your main `employee` table.

```
SELECT es.skillId, COUNT(es.employeeId) 'Number of Skill Holders',
    CASE WHEN COUNT(es.employeeId) <= 1 THEN (select top 1 t1.firstName from Employee t1 where t1.employeeId = e.id)
    ELSE 'No Skill shortage'
    END AS 'Skill status'
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeSkill] es
JOIN Employee e ON e.id = es.employeeId
group by es.skillId
```

Comment: There could be multiple Employees for a particular skill level. You have to apply TOP 1 t1.firstName in the subquery

Comment: @VenkataramanR, yes, you have the point, but we are not sure since OPs skill table is in singular form

Comment: @METAL, agreed. But, as the OP is applying GROUP BY skills and COUNT the number of employees, I think there will be more employees for a particular skill. It is better to apply TOP clause or MAX or MIN clause to avoid SUBQUERY issues.

Comment: @VenkataramanR, thanks for the suggestion, can use either `top 1` or `max(t1.firstName)`

Answer (score 2):

You are already joining with the `Employee` table, so if whenever you know that there is only 1 record (employee) with that particular skill, you can do a `MAX(e.firstName)` to display it's name, and remove the subquery.

```
SELECT 
    es.skillId, 
    COUNT(es.employeeId) 'Number of Skill Holders',
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(es.employeeId) <= 1 THEN MAX(e.firstName)
        ELSE 'No Skill shortage'
        END AS 'Skill status'
FROM 
    [dbo].[EmployeeSkill] es
    INNER JOIN Employee e ON e.id = es.employeeId
group by 
    es.skillId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query below. This will list the skills that have an employeeCount of 1. It will also display the employee first name.

```
SELECT e.firstname, 
       t.skillid 
FROM   employee e 
       JOIN (SELECT es.skillid, 
                    es.employeeid, 
                    Count(es.employeeid) 
                      OVER ( 
                        partition BY skillid) AS empcount 
             FROM   employeeskill es 
                    JOIN employee e 
                      ON es.employeeid = e.employeeid)t 
         ON e.employeeid = t.employeeid 
WHERE  empcount = 1
```